# Can I make a trade route in which the resources are traded over an specific amount?

Tags: anno-1404, anno-1404-venice

For example I want to sell ropes to the AI, but I want to always have a stash of 30 ropes in my warehouse in case I need to build a ship. Can I just export the ropes over 30? It's just too messy and tedious to micro the trade amounts all the time.

Comment: You can set a minimum threshold for goods in Anno 2070. Alas, Anno 1404 does not support the feature.

Answer (score 1):

There is a screen for this, the wiki calls it the "[Passive selling screen](http://anno1404.wikia.com/wiki/Trade#Passive_selling_screen)".

[image]

The interesting section from the article:

> On the image I set the amount to 20 which means my Warehouse will only
>   sell goods if there are more than 20 (I only sell those that are
>   surplus).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I already knew about that. I didn't clarify well my question. I was referring specifically to trade routes. Thanks nonetheless.